# Laravel joins only appear when all the joined tables contain values

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, query-builder

I have a **curriculum** table and a table of **content_texts**, **content_files**, **content_videos** and **quizzes**. All of the tables are related to **curriculum** tables with one to many, where one **curriculum** has many **content_texts**, **content_files**, **content_videos** and **quizzes**. The problem is, when I fill in all the **content_texts**, **content_files**, **content_videos** and **quizzes** tables and I join displays all of them, but when I only fill in one, all the tables that I join are not displayed.

> this is my CurriculumDisplayResource

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Curriculum;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CurriculumDisplayResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {




        return [

            'id' => $this->id,
            'title_section' => json_decode($this->title_section),
            'learning_objective'=> json_decode($this->learning_objective),
            'content_detail' =>

                DB::table('curriculums')
                    ->join('content_texts','curriculums.id','=','content_texts.curriculum_id')
                    ->join('content_files','curriculums.id','=','content_files.curriculum_id')
                    ->join('content_videos','curriculums.id','=','content_videos.curriculum_id')
                    ->join('quizzes','curriculums.id','=','quizzes.curriculum_id')
                    ->select('content_texts.title_text','content_texts.text_course',
                        'content_files.title_file','content_files.file_course','content_videos.title_video',
                        'content_videos.video_course',"quizzes.title_quiz",'quizzes.question','quizzes.answer','quizzes.right_answer')
                    ->get(),
            'parent_id' => $this->id,
        ];
    }
}
```

> this is the curriculumController

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Course;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Http\Resources\CurriculumDisplayResource;
    use App\Http\Resources\CurriculumResource;
    use App\Models\ContentText;
    use App\Models\Curriculum;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class CurriculumController extends Controller
    {

        public function index()
        {


//            return  CurriculumDisplayResource::collection(
//               DB::table('curriculums')->join('courses','courses.id','=','curriculums.course_id')->select('curriculums.*')->get());
        }


        public function store (Request $request)
        {

            $c = new Curriculum();
            $c->title_section = json_encode($request->get('title_section'));
            $c->learning_objective = json_encode($request->get('learning_objective'));
            $c->user_id = Auth::id();
            $c->course_id = $request->get('course_id');



            $c->save();

                        return response(new CurriculumDisplayResource($c));


        }

        public function show($id)
        {

            $curriculum = Curriculum::findOrFail($id);



            return response($curriculum);
        }


        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $c = Curriculum::findOrFail($id);
            $c->title_section = json_encode($request->get('title_section'));
            $c->learning_objective = json_encode($request->get('learning_objective'));
            $c->user_id = Auth::id();
            $c->course_id = $request->get('course_id');

            $c->save();

            return response(new CurriculumResource($c));
        }

        public function destroy($id)
        {
           $c = Curriculum::findOrFail($id);
           $c->delete();

           return response(null,204);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to get all result from table curriculum whether it has relation data you can use [left join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause)

left join will get the data from the left 'table' whether there is relational data or not:

```
 DB::table('curriculums')
                    ->leftJoin('content_texts','curriculums.id','=','content_texts.curriculum_id')
                    ->leftJoin('content_files','curriculums.id','=','content_files.curriculum_id')
                    ->leftJoin('content_videos','curriculums.id','=','content_videos.curriculum_id')
                    ->leftJoin('quizzes','curriculums.id','=','quizzes.curriculum_id')
                    ->select('content_texts.title_text','content_texts.text_course',
                        'content_files.title_file','content_files.file_course','content_videos.title_video',
                        'content_videos.video_course',"quizzes.title_quiz",'quizzes.question','quizzes.answer','quizzes.right_answer')
                    ->get(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the relation in eloquent to get all the relation in a more structured way

```
$curriculums = Curriculum:::whit(['contentTexts', 'contentFils', 'contentVideos', 'quizzes'])->get();
```

Where `'contentTexts', 'contentFils', 'contentVideos', 'quizzes'` are the name of the relations declared in the class `Curriculum`

**Curriculum::class**

```
public function contentText()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContentVideo::class);
}
```